# Loop inside a Variable in YAML for Ansible

Tags: ansible

So I have a script that I REALLY don't want to copy and paste about 50 times.

The typical loop suggested with {{item}} isn't working because it's already in another variable.. which is unfortunate.

I don't understand why loops are so hard to do in this language..

This is on Ansible Tower, but it should work like ansible scripts in general. I can get the code to run without the loop but the instant i put a loop in it messes up.

This fails:

```
- name: Start Instances with Persist as "No"
  ec2:
     instance_ids: "{{hostvars[groups['tag_Persist_No'][{{item}}]].ec2_id}}"
     region: us-east-1
     state: running
     wait: yes
  ignore_errors: yes
  loop:
    - 0
    - 1
```

This succeeds:

```
- name: Start Instances with Persist as "No" 0
  ec2:
     instance_ids: "{{hostvars[groups['tag_Persist_No'][0]].ec2_id}}"
     region: us-east-1
     state: running
     wait: yes
  ignore_errors: yes
- name: Start Instances with Persist as "No" 1
  ec2:
     instance_ids: "{{hostvars[groups['tag_Persist_No'][1]].ec2_id}}"
     region: us-east-1
     state: running
     wait: yes
  ignore_errors: yes
```

error is

```
template error while templating string: expected token ':'. got '}'. String: {{hostvars[groups['tag_Persist_No'][{{item}}]].ec2_id}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax to use the var in your loop:

```
instance_ids: "{{ hostvars[groups['tag_Persist_No'][item]].ec2_id }}"
```

You simply added extra curly braces that have nothing to do here since you are already inside a jinja2 template expression.

Comment: Worked like a charm - thanks.. can't believe I didn't think of this.